# What is the time complexity of a modified quick sort algorithm?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity

We use the regular quicksort algorithm. The pivot chosen is the median, but in order to find the median it takes `Theta(n^{2006/2005})` Worst case.

Why is the worst case of the algorithm equal `Theta(n^{2006/2005})` **and not** `Theta(n^{2006/2005} * logn)`?

Comment: Where is your claim about the quicklsort's complexity coming from? What is this median algorithm? does it also partially sort the array?

Comment: There is no way a comparison based sorting algorithm has complexity `Theta(n^{2006/2005})`, so there's probably a `log n` factor in there.

Comment: @IVlad `n^(1+epsilon) > nlogn` for every value of `epsilon > 0` and for large enough `n`, if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: Ok, so it's possible. Really curious about that algorithm now.

Comment: @IVlad A simple algorithm that assumes the median also partially sorts the array up to the median is easily achieved in this complexity, since you don't need to invoke on the first part of the array. I think it depends on more details than are provided.

Comment: @amit, the question doesn't reveal the algorithm. We just use it as sort of a "black-box". After finding the median we are partioning the array like with the regular quick sort.

Comment: The recurrence tree must be `logn` because each iteration we use the median to partition the array. Each iteration takes `Theta(n^{2006/2005})`. So why isn't the overall time-complexity equal `Theta(n^{2006/2005}*logn)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to understand that each "iteration" does NOT take `N^2006/2005` where `N` is the size of the ORIGINAL array, in fact - since this is a superlinear function, finding the median in 2 halves of the array is easier than finding it in the big array.

To formally prove it, we will first, define the recursive complexity formula: (for simplicity we assume the median takes exactly `n^2006/2005`, but it is easy to modify this for upper bound of `C*n^2006/2005`.)

```
T(n) = n^2006/2005 + 2T(n/2)
```

Now, we can show it by induction by proving

```
T(n) <= 2* n^2006/2005
```

The base clause here is trivial for small enough value of `n`.

Assume for each `k<n`, the assumption `T(k) <= 2*(n/2)^2006/2005` holds.

```
T(n) = n^2006/2005 + 2T(n/2) <= (i.h.) 
     <= n^2006/2005 + 2*(2*(n/2)^2006/2005) =
     = n^2006/2005 + 4 * (n/2)^2006/2005 =
     = (*) 2^(2004/2005) *n^(2006/2005) + n^(2006/2005)
     <= 2*n^(2006/2005)
```

The (*) equality comes from [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E%282006%2F2005%29%20%2B%204%20*%20%28n%2F2%29%5E%282006%2F2005%29), and you can derive it as well using some algebra on the formula.

---

Also note, this does not contradict the fact that sorting is `Omega(nlogn)`, since `n^(1+epsilon) > nlogn` for every `epsilon>0`, and for large enough values of `n`.

Comment: Thank you @amit. So basically you had the intuition the algorithm behaves almost like: `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)` and then you proved it by induction.

Comment: @AlonAlon After noticing that the superlinear function becomes cheaper and cheaper every iteration, and the sum of all subarrays of size `n/2^i` if cheaper than the finding median in the big array, it becomes clearer that it is going to dominant the log factor. You could also use master theorem here I assume, didn't try it - felt comftorable enough with induction because it also lets me understand when I am failing - why is it failing.